# How to count number of times integer multiplied by parts to reduce to single digit

Tags: for-loop, math, multiplication

Say my input is `39` - I want to correctly loop through the parts of this number until the final product is a single digit (3*9 = 27, 2*7 = 14, 1*4 = 4), and return as output the count of times multiplied, which in this example would be `3.`

My basic understanding of the loop has gotten me to step 1, where I've managed to return `27` using the example above.

```
def times_multiplied(n):
    total = 1
    for i in map(int, str(n)):
        total *= i
    return total
```

Another thought I had for reducing the number, not finding the count just yet, was to add additional for loops, but my gut said this was too much code. I'm convinced Python provides a more simple, more elegant solution....

Lastly, of course, is the method to capture the count of times multiplied, which my gut also says might have to do with Counter...I'm not positive.

Please help!

Comment: Btw, this is called the [multiplicative persistence of number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativePersistence.html) in base 10. The OEIS entry is [A031346](https://oeis.org/A031346), which incidentally, gives an example Python function similar to @GReaperEx's answer. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a direct formula, so that's about as good as you'll get.

Answer (score 2):

You should rename `times_multiplied` to `multiply_digits`, because that's what it does. Then create the real `times_multiplied`, by looping until you have a result less than ten. Here's a possible solution, if I can remember my python:

```
def multiply_digits(n):
    total = 1
    for i in map(int, str(n)):
        total *= i
    return total

def times_multiplied(n):
    count = 0
    result = n
    while result >= 10:
        count += 1
        result = multiply_digits(result)
    return count
```

In a single function:

```
def times_multiplied(n):
    count = 0
    result = n
    while result >= 10:
        count += 1
        total = 1
        for i in map(int, str(result)):
            total *= i 
        result = total
    return count
```

Comment: def persistence(n):
    total = 1
    for i in map(int, str(n)):
        total *= i
        return total
    count = 0
    result = n
    while True: 
        count += 1
        result = persistence(result)
        if result < 10:
            break
    return count

Comment: Putting all this in a single function would be messy. Are you sure you want to do it like this?

Comment: no, but for the sake of this exercise i want to be able to see how it'd work in one function. i can agree two functions makes the code much cleaner.

Comment: Test.assert_equals(persistence(39), 3)
Test.assert_equals(persistence(4), 0)
Test.assert_equals(persistence(25), 2)
Test.assert_equals(persistence(999), 4)

Comment: count = 0
    total = 1
    if n < 10:
        return 0
    for i in map(int, str(n)):
        total *= i
        return total
    while True: 
        count += 1
    return count

Comment: struggling with the last test, it's saying my output is 9 when it should be 4